# How to test for a named chest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm doing a project in Minecraft 1.10 where I want to detect a named chest and put an item in it. The player puts down a chest that's named Mailbox, and the command blocks are supposed to detect it. I tried using the `execute` command to detect the chest, and then `blockdata` to put an item in that chest, but never got to work correctly.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I have fixed my answer. It should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks don't keep names once placed. So finding a placed block with a name is not possible. Only items keep the name, once you shift their state all properties are restored to default.

**Names are not stored in blockdata!!**

But, a chest has a block entity associated with it that holds additional data about the block. The block's block entity ID is chest. As stated on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chest#Block_entity):

> **CustomName**: Optional. The name of this container, which will display in its GUI where the default name ordinarily is.
>
> **Lock**: Optional. When not blank, prevents the container from being opened unless the opener is holding an item whose name matches this string.
>
> **Items**: List of items in the container.
>
> **LootTable**: Optional. Loot table to be used to fill the chest when it is next opened, or the items are otherwise interacted with.
>
> **LootTableSeed**: Optional. Seed for generating the loot table. 0 or omitted will use a random seed. Both loot table tags will be removed once the items have been generated.

The name of a chest is stored in the `CustomName` tag. So, to test for it, run this on a superfast clock:

```
/testforblock x y z chest -1 {CustomName:"The Name"}
```

Comment: Some tile entities (chests included) will keep their names when placed.

Comment: Please read the answer in whole before you comment or downvote.

Comment: *"Please read the answer in whole before you comment or downvote"* - you only edited the correct info in after my comment and the downvote. You can see the history of the answer by clicking on the "edited Feb 25 at 2:19" hyperlink. [This is what it looked at the time of my comment.](http://i.imgur.com/Ep8hm5Q.png) You should able to submit another answer if you want to get rid of the downvotes/comments from your previously incorrect answer.